# Converting string using long arithmetic

Tags: c++, algorithm

I decided to implement addition using strings, as my numbers may be huge. The problem that I'm facing is how to convert from decimal numbers in strings to binary. If `lol` is the result of an addition, I'm trying to convert it to a binary form using:

```
unsigned long long function_arg = atoi( lol.c_str() );
```

As the number of digits grows, as for example n>14, it fails, so even `long long` is too short.  What can  you advise me to do?   Here is actually the code of my program (working with decimal system):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset> 
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

string add (string &s1, string &s2) {
  int carry=0,sum,i;
  string  min=s1,
  max=s2,
  result = "";

  if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {
    max = s1;
    min = s2;
  } else {
    max = s2;
    min = s1;
  }

  for (i = min.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
    sum = min[i] + max[i + max.length() - min.length()] + carry - 2*'0';

    carry = sum/10;
    sum %=10;

    result = (char)(sum + '0') + result;
  }

  i = max.length() - min.length()-1;

  while (i>=0) {
    sum = max[i] + carry - '0';
    carry = sum/10;
    sum%=10;

    result = (char)(sum + '0') + result;
    i--;
  }

  if (carry!=0) {
    result = (char)(carry + '0') + result;
  }       

  return result;
}


string Dex_To_bin(unsigned long long number){
  string result;
  unsigned long long bitmask = 1ULL << 63;
  do
    result.push_back(static_cast<bool>(number & bitmask));
  while (bitmask >>= 1);
  return result;
}


int main () {
  string a,b;
  cin >> a >> b;
  add(a,b);
  cout << add(a,b) << endl;
  cout << endl;
  cout << endl;
  string lol=add(a,b);
  unsigned long long funtion_arg = atoi( lol.c_str() );
  cout << Dex_To_bin(funtion_arg) << bitset<64>(funtion_arg) << endl;
  cin.get();
  cin.ignore();
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Function `add` works great, the problem is with `Dec_to_Bin` :(

Comment: Please, format your code in a correct way. Badly formatted code shows laziness and people here are less prone to help lazy coders.

Comment: And why don't you use a library for this - like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/)? It would be much faster and reliable.

Comment: Unless of course you're doing this for educational purposes...  :-)

Comment: The first problem is that you have named the method back to front. With that parameter type and return type, it is 'bin_to_dec()', not the other way around. Possibly you have confused yourself about how to implement it as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You're using strings to represent very long numbers, right?  Numbers that won't fit into standard numeric types?  The result is no different.  Think of making a set of functions that take numbers-represented-as-strings.  That's the only way they're allowed to deal with the numbers.

So, write your decimal-to-binary function to take the string directly, and convert one digit of the string at a time.

Answer (score 0):

> What can you advise me to do?

Don't. A large value can't be converted to a type that is too small. You don't need this method at all in your API, or at least you shouldn't.

BTW the method signature you have devised doesn't make sense. The parameter should have been a 'string', and the *result* should have been a 'long long'. But don't provide it.